# How to find cause of unexpected token when inserting into database?

Tags: java, database, oracle, ms-access

I'm creating a function to add a product to my database but keep running into an unexpected token error when trying to add a new clothing product.

The products are successfully added to the database when I test the program using footwear products, and I believe it is the measurement property causing the problem as

> unexpected token: L required: )

is the output log (L being the input for the measurement text field on the relevant form).

```
public int addProduct(Product newProduct)
{
    String measurement = "NULL";
    int size = 0;

    if(newProduct.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("Clothing"))
    {

        Clothing newClothing = (Clothing)newProduct;
        measurement = "'" + newClothing.getMeasurement() + "'";
    }
    else
    {

        Footwear newFootwear = (Footwear)newProduct;
        size = newFootwear.getSize();
    }


    try (Connection conn = setupConnection())
    {                   

        String sql = "INSERT INTO  Products (ProductId, ProductName, Price, StockLevel, Measurement, Size) " +
                "VALUES " +
                "('" + 
                newProduct.getProductId() + "', '" +
                newProduct.getProductName() + "', '" + 
                newProduct.getPrice() + "', '" + 
                newProduct.getStockLevel() + "', '" + 
                measurement + "', '" + 
                size +
                "')";

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();   

        int rowsAffected = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        return rowsAffected;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        String message = ex.getMessage();
        System.out.println(message);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is the code.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and look at the contents of your sql string. Then grab that string and try to execute it using another client. You will see where the problem is.

Comment: First of all, print the entire stack trace: ex.printStackTrace(); If the rows are inserted into the db table, it is not a problem with the sql statement.
But if you sometimes get this error, check the data used (as already mentioned by others).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you do a very bad thing from SQL injection security prospective by building SQL statement String.

Instead you have to use PreparedStatement with parameters.

and Second: because of that if one of your value (Measurement?) contains ' character you have exact SQL injection problem :-) resulting SQL statement is broken.

As example: you can end up with SQL like (simplified)

```
INSERT INTO  Products (ProductId, Measurement) VALUES ('123', ' 25' x 15'')
```

which definitely gives you error you got

Comment: To be clear, the bug in the code is not related to SQL injection. Mismatched quotes is the problem that OP needs to fix.

Comment: sure, still problem has same root cause as SQL Injection problem. I just always mention about it when see some body try to go this way. And use PreparedStatement will solve both flaws

Comment: The diagnosis is good; the answer would be even more helpful if you recommended a remedy (other than the obvious one, about which you are 100% right: use Prepared Statement). Namely, use the q quotation mechanism, so that verbatim single quotes in the input strings do not cause errors.

Comment: There is no other option than use PreparedStatement and I already told why.. Sorry I had no time to give a solution how to use it, and it can be easily found in any SQL/JDBC tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks good but your numeric values are being inserted as VarChar. I assume that  newProduct.getPrice and Size are Numeric values. Numeric columns cant be inserted with single quotes.

Comment: Not necessary. DB may have implicit type conversion and can allow to do that. In this case I guess it is Oracle and Oracle allows it.

Comment: You are right, not necessarily. But we dont know which DB hes using.